# Using token-based together with cookie-based authentication without email

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt, asp.net-identity

I'm working on .NET Core MVC project with Identity. I have a working project currently with normal cookie-based authentication, excerpt from Identity config:

```
public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            services.AddDbContext<TauManagerIdentityDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseNpgsql(
                    context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("TauManagerIdentityDbContextConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddRoleManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<TauManagerIdentityDbContext>()
                .AddUserManager<ApplicationIdentityUserManager>()
                .AddDefaultUI()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        });
    }
}
```

I'm using `AuthorizeAttribute` to control access of different roles to different actions in my web application.

Now I am now facing a situation where I have to use some kind of token-based authentication for one specific action only. I have read several articles and questions at SO about JWT setup with .NET Core Identity, the closest one I've found to my case is [Using Identity with token and cookie authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47197402/using-identity-with-token-and-cookie-authentication).

However, I have two questions:

- Is this indeed the simplest method of generating auth tokens for such scenario?
- All examples of JWT I've seen so far contain a reference to user's email, e.g. add `new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Email)` to the list of claims when generating tokens. I do NOT collect users' emails at all, and this is a deliberate decision I'd like to keep. Is there any way to use e.g. username instead?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The sub token of JWT is just any user identifier. If your usernames are unique you can use these instead, or use their database primary key, or give each user in your database a random GUID for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this indeed the simplest method of generating auth tokens for such scenario?

I assume this is in reference to the code in the question [Using Identity with token and cookie authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47197402/using-identity-with-token-and-cookie-authentication) :

```
var claims = new[]
{
  new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Email),
  new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
};

var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Tokens:Key"]));
var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Tokens:Issuer"],
  _config["Tokens:Issuer"],
  claims,
  expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
  signingCredentials: creds);
```

When Creating a [JWT](https://jwt.io/introduction/) the two piece of information you have to provide as a programmer are the Claims and how the Signature is created.  In the previous code, the `claims` as the claims you need and the `key` and `creds` are required to create the signature.  To create a full token, you use the `JwtSecurityToken` class to create the token.  I don't know how this can be any simpler.

> Is there any way to use e.g. username instead?

Claims are whatever you want them to be.  The [System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt?view=azure-dotnet) has few built-in claim names you can use from [JwtRegisteredClaimNames Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtregisteredclaimnames?view=azure-dotnet).

So you could use one of the following:

```
JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId
JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sid
JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName
```

or you can create your own.

I think the underlying question is, *how do I make sure my JWT authorizes automatically against ASP.Net Identity*.  If you're using cookies, you should be able to look at the `ClaimsPrinciple` and determine what claims are being used by Identity to Authenticate a request and put those same claims in your JWT.

**Update 1**

I'm currently only using JWT with Angular for a project.  My code won't be complete because some of it will be specific to only using JWT/Bearer but it should help.  I believe the most important part is the `AddJwtBearer` which if I'm not mistaken, will look for a `bearer` header valid/decode and populate the `httpcontext.user` with a `ClaimsPrincipal` with all the associated claims.  These claims can be used with the `AuthorizeAttribute` to do authorization (claims and/or policies).

StartUp.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(jwtIssuerOptionsConfig)
            .Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(symmetricSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512);
            });

        services
            .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    IssuerSigningKey = symmetricSecurityKey,
                    RequireSignedTokens = true,
                    RequireExpirationTime = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidAudience = jwtIssuerOptions.Audience,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = jwtIssuerOptions.Issuer
                };
                if (_isDevelopment)
                {
                    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                    {
                        OnAuthenticationFailed = c =>
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(c.Exception.Message);
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        },
                    };
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll check out the claims from current Identity setup and see if I can put the same ones into JWT, that's a really helpful advice!

Comment: I added some additional information would use be very helpful.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, since it answers my questions perfectly, even though in the end I went different way (I'll add another answer with my solution). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, in the end I went different way. In my case I felt JWT would be an overkill, since I was going to store the resulting token in browser's local storage (low security) - hence I decided not to use JWT at all. If someone can intercept a JWT token, they technically gain at least *some* access privileges of the user and I'd need to fine tune the permissions inside JWT very well in order to make it safe.

So, I have just implemented an action that would generate a random bytestring (using `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator`) and store it as an attribute of the `IdentityUser` object.

I have also decorated the action I wanted to expose to token-based access with `[AllowAnonymous]` and added my own verification routine there (basically checking whether current `ControllerBase.User` has proper rights OR the passed token parameter has a value that belongs to one of the users who have privilege to call respective action). I realize that this opens the door for some extra security risks (such as potential DDOS on this endpoint, which would partially be mitigated if I didn't open it up), but that's the trade-off I'm willing to take.

Comment: JWT is just as secure as a cookie.  Not that I'm attempting to change your mind, just so anyone else who reads this understands the same thing.  (Although technically they aren't the same thing, as you could use a cookie to store a JWT.)

Comment: Yep, this is the whole point - since I'm storing the token in LS (and LS is less safe than cookies) - I shouldn't use neither JWT, nor cookies, but rather a token with as little functionality and access as possible.

Comment: Also, if you do plan on using storage, I Highly Recommend Session Storage over Local Storage if you can.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, but the explanation why will be way too specific and long. Thanks for your help and comments once again!